# Queue Test via HCK API Error

Tags: c#, testing, drivers

I'm using HCK API with C#, but I cant start tests. 
That is my code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string controller = "win2012-3701";
            var manager = new DatabaseProjectManager(controller);
            string projectName = "test";
            Project project;
            project = manager.GetProject(projectName);
            var targetList = new List<Target>();
            foreach (var pi in project.GetProductInstances())
            {
                targetList.AddRange(pi.GetTargets());
            }
            targetList.First().GetTests().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
            project.QueueTest();
        }
```

This project has tests for one driver(one SYS file). In console i have 20 tests. But on the last line i have exception: `Could not schedule this test (Registry Callback Tests)`, and this exception has inner exception: `{" 'Alias'  associated with  'Schedule'  does not exist in the data store  'Alias' ."}`.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is auth error. My program login in controller in this account or default guest account. And guest haven't right :(. To solve this problem I need create same logins in controller and machine where i start program.